# Adding random term into glmer mixed-effect model; error message: failure to converge

Tags: r, lme4, random-effects

I'm analyzing data from an experiment, replicated in time, where I measured plant emergence at the soil surface. I had 3 experimental runs, represented by the term `trialnum`, and would like to include `trialnum` as a random effect.

Here is a summary of variables involved:

```
data.frame: 768 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ trialnum : Factor w/ 2 levels "2","3": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Flood    : Factor w/ 4 levels "0","5","10","15": 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Burial   : Factor w/ 4 levels "1.3","2.5","5",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ biotype  : Factor w/ 6 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 ...
 $ soil     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ n        : num  15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 ...
```

Where `trialnum` is the experimental run, `Flood`, `Burial`, and `biotype` are input/independent variables, and `soil` is the response/dependent variable.

I previously created this model with all input variables:

```
glmfitALL <-glm(cbind(soil,n)~trialnum*Flood*Burial*biotype,family = binomial(logit),total)`
```

From this model I found that by running

```
anova(glmfitALL, test = "Chisq")
```

`trialnum` is significant. There were 3 experimental runs, I'm only including 2 of those in my analysis. I have been advised to incorporate `trialnum` as a random effect so that I do not have to report the experimental runs separately.

To do this, I created the following model:

```
glmerfitALL <-glmer(cbind(soil,n)~Flood*Burial*biotype + (1|trialnum), 
data = total, 
family = binomial(logit), 
control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"))
```

From this I get the following error message:

`maxfun < 10 * length(par)^2 is not recommended. Unable to evaluate scaled gradientModel failed to converge: degenerate Hessian with 9 negative eigenvalues`

I have tried running this model in a variety of ways including:

```
glmerfitALL <-glmer(cbind(soil,n)~Flood*Burial*biotype*(1|trialnum), 
data = total, 
family = binomial(logit), 
control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"))
```

as well as incorporating `REML=FALSE` and used `optimx` in place of `bobyqa`, but all reiterations resulted in a similar error message.

1. Because this is an "eigenvalue" error, does that mean there is a problem with my source file/original data?
2. I also found previous threads regarding the `lmer4` error messages (sorry I did not save the link), and saw some comments raising issue with the lack of replicates of the random effect. Because I only have 2 replicates `trialnum2` and `trialnum3`, am I able to even run `trialnum` as a random effect?

Comment: see `?convergence` for things to try rethe glmer fit. (a quick comment on your models - the glm fits 192 parameters which is quite a lot for your size of data / are there enough cases to support that, and s the notations perhaps `cbind(soil, n - soil)` ? . For the RE, there wont be a good estimate of the variance as `trialnum` has only two groups)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the eigenvalue, the chief recommendation for this is [centring and/or scaling predictors](https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/pandoc/lme4.html).

Regarding the RE groups, around [five are an approximate minimum](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html).